# Solving the N Queens Puzzle in AEC using stack

Tags: assembly, x86, n-queens

N Queens Puzzle is a puzzle which asks you to place N chess queens on an NxN chess board so that no two queens are attacking each other. Two queens are attacking each other if they are on the same row, diagonal or column. [I solved it using recursion in the dialect of AEC that's targeting WebAssembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289652/solving-the-n-queens-puzzle-in-aec-using-recursion). However, the dialect of AEC that's targeting x86 doesn't support custom functions (let alone recursion), so I cannot solve it the same way in it. So I solved it in the AEC dialect targeting x86 using stack instead of using recursion.

```lisp
;A very advanced example: Solving the n-Queens Puzzle.
; https://flatassembler.github.io/nQueensPuzzle.html
AsmStart
    macro pushIntegerToTheSystemStack x
    {
        sub esp,4
        fld dword [x]
        fistp dword [esp]
    }
    macro pushPointerToTheSystemStack x
    {
        sub esp,4
        lea ebx,[x]
        mov [esp],ebx
    }
    macro pushStringToTheSystemStack x
    {
        sub esp,4
        mov dword [esp],x
    }
    format PE console
    entry start

    include 'win32a.inc'

    section '.text' code executable
    start:
AsmEnd
enterTheNumberString <= "Enter the number of queens.", 10, 0
floatSign <= "%f", 0
AsmStart
    pushPointerToTheSystemStack enterTheNumberString
    call [printf]
    add esp, 4 ;Cleaning up the system stack. When writing in assembly, there is no compiler to do that for you.
    pushPointerToTheSystemStack n
    pushPointerToTheSystemStack floatSign
    call [scanf]
    add esp, 8
AsmEnd
topOfMyStack := 1
numberOfSolutions := 0
myStack[topOfMyStack * (n + 1)] := 0
While topOfMyStack > 0
    howManyQueensAreOnTheBoard := myStack[topOfMyStack * (n + 1)]
    i := 0
    While i < howManyQueensAreOnTheBoard
        queens[i] := myStack[topOfMyStack * (n + 1) + i + 1]
        i := i + 1
    EndWhile
    topOfMyStack := topOfMyStack - 1
    If howManyQueensAreOnTheBoard = n
        numberOfSolutions := numberOfSolutions + 1
        i := 0
        While i < n
            integerSignFollowedBySpace <= "%d ", 0
            'A' + i ;The compiler will store this into the variable "result"
            AsmStart
                pushIntegerToTheSystemStack result
                call [putchar]
                add esp, 4
            AsmEnd
            queens[i] + 1
            AsmStart
                pushIntegerToTheSystemStack result
                pushPointerToTheSystemStack integerSignFollowedBySpace
                call [printf]
                add esp, 8
            AsmEnd
            i := i + 1
        EndWhile
        AsmStart
            pushPointerToTheSystemStack newLineString
            call [printf]
            add esp, 4
        AsmEnd
        twoSpacesAndPlus <= "  +",0
        AsmStart
            pushPointerToTheSystemStack twoSpacesAndPlus
            call [printf]
            add esp, 4
        AsmEnd
        column := 0
        While column < n
            minusFollowedByPlus <= "-+", 0
            AsmStart
                pushPointerToTheSystemStack minusFollowedByPlus
                call [printf]
                add esp, 4
            AsmEnd
            column := column + 1
        EndWhile
        AsmStart
            pushPointerToTheSystemStack newLineString
            call [printf]
            add esp, 4
        AsmEnd
        row := n - 1
        While row > 0 | row = 0
            integerSignPrecededBySpace <= " %d",0
            integerSign <= "%d",0
            If row + 1 < 10
                row + 1
                AsmStart
                    pushIntegerToTheSystemStack result
                    pushPointerToTheSystemStack integerSignPrecededBySpace
                    call [printf]
                    add esp, 8
                AsmEnd
            Else
                row + 1
                AsmStart
                    pushIntegerToTheSystemStack result
                    pushPointerToTheSystemStack integerSign
                    call [printf]
                    add esp, 8
                AsmEnd
            EndIf
            '|'
            AsmStart
                pushIntegerToTheSystemStack result
                call [putchar]
                add esp,4
            AsmEnd
            column := 0
            While column < n
                (queens[column] = row) ? 'Q' : (mod(row + column, 2) = 1) ? ' ' : '*'
                AsmStart
                    pushIntegerToTheSystemStack result
                    call [putchar]
                    add esp, 4
                AsmEnd
                '|'
                AsmStart
                    pushIntegerToTheSystemStack result
                    call [putchar]
                    add esp,4
                AsmEnd
                column := column + 1
            EndWhile
            AsmStart
                pushPointerToTheSystemStack newLineString
                call [printf]
                add esp, 4
            AsmEnd
            row := row - 1
            column := 0
            AsmStart
                pushPointerToTheSystemStack twoSpacesAndPlus
                call [printf]
                add esp, 4
            AsmEnd
            While column < n
                AsmStart
                    pushPointerToTheSystemStack minusFollowedByPlus
                    call [printf]
                    add esp, 4
                AsmEnd
                column := column + 1
            EndWhile
            AsmStart
                pushPointerToTheSystemStack newLineString
                call [printf]
                add esp, 4
            AsmEnd
        EndWhile
        threeSpaces <= "   ", 0
        AsmStart
            pushPointerToTheSystemStack threeSpaces
            call [printf]
            add esp, 4
        AsmEnd
        column := 0
        While column < n
            'A' + column
            AsmStart
                pushIntegerToTheSystemStack result
                call [putchar]
                add esp, 4
            AsmEnd
            ' '
            AsmStart
                pushIntegerToTheSystemStack result
                call [putchar]
                add esp, 4  
            AsmEnd
            column := column + 1
        EndWhile
        AsmStart
            pushPointerToTheSystemStack newLineString
            call [printf]
            add esp, 4
        AsmEnd
    Else
        rowOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd := n - 1
        columnOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd := howManyQueensAreOnTheBoard
        While rowOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd > 0 | rowOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd = 0
            isThereAQueenInTheSameRow := 0
            i := 0
            While i < howManyQueensAreOnTheBoard
                If queens[i] = rowOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd
                    isThereAQueenInTheSameRow := 1
                EndIf
                i := i + 1
            EndWhile
            isThereAQueenOnTheSameGlavnaDijagonala := 0 ;Sorry, I don't know how to say "glavna dijagonala" and "sporedna dijagonala" in English, and I am not wasting my time looking that up.
            i := 0
            While i < howManyQueensAreOnTheBoard
                If queens[i] + i = rowOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd + columnOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd
                    isThereAQueenOnTheSameGlavnaDijagonala := 1
                EndIf
                i := i + 1
            EndWhile
            isThereAQueenOnTheSameSporednaDijagonala := 0
            i := 0
            While i < howManyQueensAreOnTheBoard
                If queens[i] - i = rowOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd - columnOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd
                    isThereAQueenOnTheSameSporednaDijagonala := 1
                EndIf
                i := i + 1
            EndWhile
            isThereAQueenOnTheSameDiagonal := isThereAQueenOnTheSameGlavnaDijagonala = 1 | isThereAQueenOnTheSameSporednaDijagonala = 1
            If not(isThereAQueenInTheSameRow = 1) & not(isThereAQueenOnTheSameDiagonal = 1)
                topOfMyStack := topOfMyStack + 1
                myStack[topOfMyStack * (n + 1)] := howManyQueensAreOnTheBoard + 1
                i := 0
                While i < howManyQueensAreOnTheBoard
                    myStack[topOfMyStack * (n + 1) + i + 1] := queens[i]
                    i := i + 1
                EndWhile
                myStack[topOfMyStack * (n + 1) + howManyQueensAreOnTheBoard + 1] := rowOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd
            EndIf
            rowOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd := rowOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd - 1
        EndWhile
    EndIf
EndWhile
foundSolutionsString <= "Found %d solutions!", 10, 0
AsmStart
    pushIntegerToTheSystemStack numberOfSolutions
    pushPointerToTheSystemStack foundSolutionsString
    call [printf]
    add esp, 8
    invoke system, _pause
    invoke exit, 0

    _pause db "PAUSE",0
    newLineString db 10,0

    section '.rdata' readable writable
    result dd ?
    n dd ?
    myStack dd 1024 dup(?)
    queens dd 16 dup(?)
    topOfMyStack dd ?
    i dd ?
    numberOfSolutions dd ?
    howManyQueensAreOnTheBoard dd ?
    rowOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd dd ?
    columnOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd dd ?
    isThereAQueenInTheSameRow dd ?
    isThereAQueenOnTheSameGlavnaDijagonala dd ?
    isThereAQueenOnTheSameSporednaDijagonala dd ?
    isThereAQueenOnTheSameDiagonal dd ?
    row dd ?
    column dd ?

    section '.idata' data readable import
        library msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll' ;Microsoft Visual C Runtime Library (comes with Windows 98 and newer).
            import msvcrt,printf,'printf',system,'system',exit,'exit',scanf,'scanf',putchar,'putchar'
AsmEnd
```

You have [the `.exe` file in this ZIP archive](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler/raw/master/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler.zip), it is called `nQueensPuzzle.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> macro pushIntegerToTheSystemStack x
> macro pushPointerToTheSystemStack x
> macro pushStringToTheSystemStack x
> ```

> ```
> integerSignFollowedBySpace <= "%d ", 0
> twoSpacesAndPlus <= "  +",0
> minusFollowedByPlus <= "-+", 0
> ```

> ```
> howManyQueensAreOnTheBoard dd ?
> rowOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd dd ?
> columnOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd dd ?
> isThereAQueenInTheSameRow dd ?
> isThereAQueenOnTheSameGlavnaDijagonala dd ?
> isThereAQueenOnTheSameSporednaDijagonala dd ?
> isThereAQueenOnTheSameDiagonal dd ?
> ```

Throughout your program, I see these very descriptive names for the user-defined symbols (macro, string, variable, ...). I'm just not too sure that their extreme lengths aren't impairing readability. Not everybody uses a super-wide screen (or a tiny-characters font).
FASM has a line continuation character, so maybe you could use it to turn

```
isThereAQueenOnTheSameDiagonal := isThereAQueenOnTheSameGlavnaDijagonala = 1 | isThereAQueenOnTheSameSporednaDijagonala = 1
```

into the slightly more readable:

```
isThereAQueenOnTheSameDiagonal :=\
 isThereAQueenOnTheSameGlavnaDijagonala = 1 |\
 isThereAQueenOnTheSameSporednaDijagonala = 1
```

---

> ;Sorry, I don't know how to say "glavna dijagonala" and "sporedna dijagonala" in English, and I am not wasting my time looking that up.

**LMGTFY**

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal are mentioned a lot of possible translations. I prefer next replacements:

```
isThereAQueenOnTheSameMainDiagonal dd ?
isThereAQueenOnTheSameAntiDiagonal dd ?
```

But wait, it gets better: *you don't need these variables at all*. I closely looked at the program and found that they're short-lived and only have to hold a couple of temporary values that you immediately after combine in the *isThereAQueenOnTheSameDiagonal* variable. I suggest next improved version requiring but a single `While` loop:

```
isThereAQueenOnTheSameDiagonal := 0
i := 0
While i < howManyQueensAreOnTheBoard
  If queens[i] + i = rowOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd + columnOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd
    isThereAQueenOnTheSameDiagonal := 1
  EndIf
  If queens[i] - i = rowOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd - columnOfTheQueenWeAreAboutToAdd
    isThereAQueenOnTheSameDiagonal := 1
  EndIf
  i := i + 1
EndWhile
```

---

> ```
> macro pushPointerToTheSystemStack x
> {
>     sub esp,4
>     lea ebx,[x]
>     mov [esp],ebx
> }
> macro pushStringToTheSystemStack x
> {
>     sub esp,4
>     mov dword [esp],x
> }
> ```

Why does this *pushPointerToTheSystemStack* macro use the EBX register? And why does it use `LEA` instead of the more efficient `MOV`?
You can write it identically to the *pushStringToTheSystemStack* macro. And if you care about codesize, then just write `push x` within the macro.
Or alternatively, don't waste a macro and directly write the `push` instruction in the ASM block (eg. `pushPointerToTheSystemStack enterTheNumberString` becomes `push enterTheNumberString`).